# Grant access to just one schema in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-schema, pgadmin

I have a user `just_one_schema_user`.

In my database I have two schemas: `public` and `sample`

How can I make this user to see just the `sample`?

This is what I did:

`GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA sample TO just_one_schema_user`

`REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public FROM just_one_schema_user`

But the user still can list the tables in `public` and see their structures.

Comment: I guess this is not possible. All structural information are stored in the schema ```pg_catalog``` and you cannot revoke the privileges on this schema, since the user would lose his ability to look up any objects from any schema.

Comment: @Islingre You are right about `pg_catalog`. However, the question is about `public`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes it is. But as long as I have access to ```pg_catalog```, I should be able to see the schema, should I not? I am not sure, but I would be surprised if revoking privileges on some other schema would affect queries to the catalog.

Comment: Oh, you are correct, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

#### About access to the table metadata:

As Islingre commented, there is no good way to hide that information from users.

You would have to deny the user access to the `pg_class`, `pg_namespace` and `pg_proc` and similar tables. This *can* be done if you set `allow_system_table_mods` to `on`, and PostgreSQL will continue functioning, but a lot of things will no longer work:

- Using the `psql` utility commands like `\d` or `\dt`
- Similar tools for other tools
- Monitoring systems

Essentially, you won't be able to see *any* metadata any more.

There is no way to allow a user to see only some of the metadata, it is all or nothing.

But that is not a problem. There is no good reason to keep metadata from anybody - that is public information.

PostgreSQL doesn't consider that a security problem. Just because I know that there is a table `customer` with a column `credit_card_number` doesn't get me any closer to accessing it if permissions are set properly.

#### About access *to the objects* in `public`:

A `REVOKE` that removes a privilege that has never been granted will silently do nothing.

The `USAGE` privilege on schema `public` is granted to `PUBLIC`, not `just_one_schema_user`.

Use this to show the permissions in `psql`:

```
\dn+
```

You are looking for:

```
REVOKE CREATE, USAGE ON SCHEMA public FROM public;
```

I would recommend storing no application data in `public`, only extensions. Then don't revoke `USAGE`, only `CREATE`.